# What's the difference between 'shot' and 'shot at'?

Tags: meaning, difference

There are two sentences like this.

1. The hunter shot at the bird.
2. The hunter shot the bird.

Maybe I think that 'shot at' in number 1 sentence means that the hunter shot the bird but missed it. whereas hunter in number 2 sentence succeeded.
What's the difference between 'shot' and 'shot at'in meaning?
Please, tell me the difference.

Comment: It's not shot and shot at. It shot and shot |at the bird|.

Answer (score 3):

You're mostly correct. "Shot at" means that the hunter *did* fire a shot, and that it was fired *toward* the bird, likely also that the hunter was *trying* to shoot the bird. It doesn't imply for sure that he did or didn't *hit* the bird (except for the contextual implication that if he did hit the bird, why didn't you just say "he shot the bird"?).